# react: reach the component's parent or transfer data from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-native, inheritance

Please tell me how you can in this scheme

```
render()
{
    return (
<Parent>
    <Child1>
    <Child2>
</Parent>
    );
}
```

on the side of the components `Parent` and `Child` get the data that will be generated in the `render ()` method or in the constructor (data access)

It is clear that one of the ways is to transfer to `props`, but if without it?

For example, a state is set, in the `Parent` constructor, this state of the parent is obtained and the same state is set, in the `Child` constructor, the `Parent` state is obtained and its state is set. As a result, some parameter is passed across the tree.

But in order to implement this, you need to somehow gain access to the parent of the component.

For example:

more beautiful option (and I do not know how to implement it - this option would be more preferable)

```
this.state = {
    mydata: 123;
};

class Parent extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.state = {
            mydata: this.getOwner().state.mydata; // = 123
        };
    }
}

class Child extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.state = {
            mydata: this.getOwner().state.mydata; // = 123
        };
    }
}
```

less beautiful option (I know how to implement it)

```
render()
{
    return (
<Parent mydata = "123">
    <Child1 mydata = "123">
    <Child2 mydata = "123">
</Parent>
    );
}

class Parent extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super();

        this.state = {
            mydata: props.mydata
        };
    }
}

class Child extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super();

        this.state = {
            mydata: props.mydata
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve the wanted result by using something called ***Context*** as the following:

```
 //outside of your class component
    const MyContext = React.CreateContext();
//inside your class component
        state = {mydata: "123"}

        render()
        {
            return (
        <MyContext value={this.state}>
        <Parent>
            <Child1>
            <Child2>
        </Parent>
        </MyContext>
            );
        }
```

now inside any of the tree components: `Parent` `Child1` and `Child2` you can reach the value of the shared state by saying `this.context.mydata`

learn more at https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html